# Validation of date input - Fix java.lang.numberformatexception error

Tags: java, date, runtime-error

I was required to make a program that would take a user inputted date and check for several criteria: date length, leap year, month accuracy, day accuracy, etc... and I believe I have gotten everything figured out except for when I test the date "12/345/678" I get a series of Java errors including:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/678"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at DateChecker.main(DateChecker.java:42)
```

I believe that this is because when java attempts to extract "yearString" it is unable to because it has been converted to integers using intparser and the inputted code now contains a "/" so the same error would occur with the date "1/234/5678" because monthString is looking for all integers, but it now contains a "/".

I am aware of the code below as I have read through another StackOverflow post with a similar issue, although when I tried to apply this to my program I got a series of compiler errors because my variables were now closed off from the rest of the program

```
try{
   int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
   ...
}
```

Here is the code that I have so far, and thanks in advance for any help that is provided :)

```
import java.util.*;

public class DateChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //activates the keyboard

        String dateString; //variable declaration

        System.out.println("Please enter a date in the format (mm/dd/yyyy): "); //prints to screen
        dateString = keyboard.nextLine();//user enters dateString value

        if (dateString.length()>10)//checks if date is greater than 10
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid date."); //prints to screen
            System.out.println("To many characters in the date.");//prints to screen
        } 
        else if(dateString.length()<10)//checks if date is less than 10
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
            System.out.println("To few characters in the date.");//prints to screen
        }
        else {//date = 10
            if(dateString.charAt(2)!='/' && dateString.charAt(5)!='/')//checks for "/" at spots 2 and 5
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
                System.out.println("Incorrect format.");//prints to screen
            }
            else{//"/" at spots 2 and 5
                //declares variables and extracts strings
                String yearString = dateString.substring(6, 10);
                String dayString = dateString.substring(3, 5);
                String monthString = dateString.substring(0, 2);

                //converts string variables to integer
                int monthInt=Integer.parseInt(monthString);
                int dayInt=Integer.parseInt(dayString);
                int yearInt=Integer.parseInt(yearString);

                if(monthInt < 1|| monthInt > 12)//checks if valid month is entered
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
                    System.out.println("Month is not valid.");//prints to screen
                }
                else
                {//month is valid
                    if(dayInt < 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid date.");
                        System.out.println("Day is not valid.");
                    }

                    else {
                        if((monthInt == 4 || monthInt == 6 || monthInt == 9 || monthInt == 11) && dayInt > 30)//checks if months should have 30 days
                        {
                            System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
                            System.out.println("Day is not valid.");//prints to screen
                        }
                        else
                            if (yearInt % 4 ==0 && (monthInt == 2 && dayInt > 29))//checks if leap year
                            {
                                System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
                                System.out.println("Day is not valid.");//prints to screen
                            }

                            else//if not leap year
                                if (yearInt % 4 != 0 && dayInt > 28)//checks if normal year
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
                                    System.out.println("Day is not valid.");//prints to screen
                                }

                                else //date entered was valid
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Valid date.");
                                }
                    }
                }
            }                   


        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: use java Date class to parse date.you don't need to do all of this yourself.

Comment: I do not understand why you are doing all this.  If the DateFormatter fails then it is an invalid date - end of story.

Comment: You cant catch all possible input errors with if statements. That's why exception catching exists. Also, verbose messages are great, but overkill. "Invalid date" is probably enough of an error message.

Comment: I am aware that java has a date checker, but I was required to do all of the if statements as part of an assignment, along with all of the irrelevant error messaging system.out statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the problem lies here :-

```
if(dateString.charAt(2)!='/' && dateString.charAt(5)!='/') //checks for "/" at spots 2 and 5 
{ 
    System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
    System.out.println("Incorrect format.");//prints to screen 
}
```

Here you're looking for both condition to be true instead you should be using **OR** in place of **AND**

This a small change you need to do:-

```
if(dateString.charAt(2)!='/' || dateString.charAt(5)!='/') //checks for "/" at spots 2 and 5 
{ 
    System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
    System.out.println("Incorrect format.");//prints to screen 
}
```

I would recommend you to use Date Class given by JAVA

Thank You,
Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use something like [`DateTimeFormatter.parse(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) Case in point is that your rules for leap years are incorrect. If the year is divisible by 100 it is not a leap year even though the year is divisible by 4 unless it is also divisible by 400. In which case it is a leap year.

Dates are hard even before you head into timezone land...

Comment: No time in this question

Comment: @ScaryWombat You are right, better to use DateTimeFormatter directly, if your not doing anything else with the date... Changed my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

How about using classes that already exist

```
System.out.println("Please enter a date in the format (mm/dd/yyyy): "); //prints to screen
String dateString = keyboard.nextLine();//user enters dateString value

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy");

try {
   sdf.parse (dateString);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.out.println("Invalid date.");//prints to screen
}
```